# Verify standard deviation of position samples with reference

Tags: measurements, data-analysis, data

Given are the reference data samples of a moving object and data samples that are obtained from a radar sensor with corresponding standard deviations for each sample point $\sigma_t$. I would like to check weather the provided standard deviations from the sensor make sense and if the data is gaussian distributed.

The data consists of x, y position, orientation $\theta$.

Usually to obtain the standard deviations for x, y and orientation $\theta$, I would compare the single samples of the sensor with a mean value $\mu$.

$$
\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=0}^n (x_i - \mu)^2}
$$

Since the position for x and y is not centered around a single point (a single mean value doesn't exist), is it correct to assume that the given reference samples are the mean values?

$$
\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=0}^n (x_i - \mu_i^{reference})^2}
$$

To check if the data is gaussian distributed I use matlab to plot the histogram and then fit a normal distribution. The result looks gaussian but I am not sure if this is really the correct approach, especially because I don't have a single mean value.

Comment: Why don't you have a mean value in x? With Gaussian distributions, isn't there a peak at the mean x?

Comment: @KyleKanos I don't have a single mean for  x because the x position is changing due to the movement of the object. When I compute the error of the sensor measurements with respect to the reference data (2nd equation), the error of x looks gaussian distributed and I get a single mean value which is close to zero. However, I am not sure if this approach is correct, since the mean value changes (corresponding value of the reference data).

Comment: I guess one expects that, for example, $f(x)\sim \alpha x +\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma)$, so the error is normally distributed